# Access button in ListBoxItem in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, button, listboxitem, itemtemplate

Hey everyone. I'm new to Silverlight and would like to access a button control that is part of a ListBoxItem. However, I'm not quite sure how to do this. My XAML is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate2">
            <Grid Height="51">
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Text="{Binding Property1}" Margin="0,0,98,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnInfo"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-11,0,0" Width="87" Height="54" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF8EC1D2" BorderBrush="#FF8EC1D2" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Image Source="../Images/btnNameImage.png" Stretch="None"/>                 
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

How can I access the "btnInfo" from the code-behind?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What property of btnInfo are you trying to access? You should be able to use it by "btnInfo" directly...

Comment: It's part of a DataTemplate so it will be in a different namescope than the page's XAML and won't be accessible directly in the code-behind. What exactly are you trying to do with the button?

Comment: I'd like to change the Image of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wont be able to access it directly from code behind, but you should be able to do what you want by registering an event with it.  Add a `Loaded` event to the button then in your codebehind define the corresponding method.

```
protected btninfo_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnInfo = (Button) sender;
    //do whatever you need to do
}
```

obviously you can do the same thing to handle click events or whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to perform this for every button in the list, not just the selected one. I also tried creating a storyboard for the image replacement, but I can't access the storyboard from the code behind.

Comment: this should run whenever one of your DataTemplates is loaded into a Template, is this not happening?  can you please show more of your code (like the ItemsControl that is hosting the templates?

Comment: Thanks. I needed to get access of the buttons from outside any of the button events themselves. So I stored each button in an array (in the laoded event) and make the array a class level variable. This works fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question of programatically accessing a data template, but how about Binding?